# Jinja nested rendering on variable content

Tags: python, jinja2

Say I have actual jinja template code in a variable X. Let us say the content of X is "{{ some_other_variable }}".

How can I display X while also rendering its content?

e.g., this does not work:

{{ X }}

As it simply renders this to screen "{{ some_other_variable }}" rather than the contents of some_other_variable.

The reason I'm doing it this way is that I have a site in which (trusted) users can create posts which themselves may contain jinja template code. The view page displays these posts, but due to the above problem, renders them directly, rather than substituting variables as I'd like.

Comment: Where does `{{ some_other_variable }}` template comes from? Can't you render it there and passed rendered? That's what I did when I had the same question. Additionally: if it's dynamic, what about the injection-risk?

Answer (score 15):

I know it's a bit late :) but here's one solution without impacting template code:

```
import jinja2
def recursive_render(tpl, values):
     prev = tpl
     while True:
         curr = jinja2.Template(prev).render(**values)
         if curr != prev:
             prev = curr
         else:
             return curr
```

Test run:

```
>>> recursive_render("Hello {{X}}!", dict(X="{{name}}", name="world"))
u'Hello world!'
```

Note that this is not very efficient, since the template must be reparsed from scratch on every iteration.

Answer (score 5):

Create new filter:

```
from jinja2 import contextfilter, Markup

@contextfilter
def subrender_filter(context, value):
    _template = context.eval_ctx.environment.from_string(value)
    result = _template.render(**context)
    if context.eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result

env = Environment()
env.filters['subrender'] = subrender_filter
```

And then use it in template:

```
{{ "Hello, {{name}}"|subrender }}
```

Comment: Seems like the cleanest solution to me!

Answer (score 2):

I thought of an interesting way to do this:

- Set up a dictionary
- Wrap a DictLoader around it (but keep a reference to the dictionary around)
- Pass a ChainLoader with the DictLoader and your normal Loader to the environment
- Implement a custom filter that adds its parameters to the aforementioned dictionary
- Use the `include` directive to call the template code in the current context

Haven't tried it, but it just might work!

Comment: custom filter could do anything, you didn't even need step 1 to 3. you could pass variables through jinja. Is there anything else that would handle replacement of variables through jinja only not manual like this.

Comment: Huh? The filter just passes on the template contents and puts them in the template dictionary so that Jinja can process them in the usual way. The tricky part is getting Jinja's context (so that you can use it to process the template). Also, why don't you want to use a custom filter?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with, using the [finalize](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#high-level-api) option for the Environment:

```
def render (tpl, args):
    scope = {}
    scope['env'] = jinja2.Environment (finalize=lambda x: scope['env'].from_string (x).render (**args) if isinstance(x, str) and '{{' in x else x)
    scope['env'].filters['q'] = lambda value: re.sub (r'"', r'\\"', value)
    return scope['env'].from_string (tpl).render (**args)
```

It's a bit ugly, so improvements welcome :)

But it does the recursive rendering as the OP was asking for, and doesn't stop until there is no more `{{` in the output..

Example session

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> def render (tpl, args):
...         scope = {}
...         scope['env'] = jinja2.Environment (finalize=lambda x: scope['env'].from_string (x).render (**args) if isinstance(x, str) and '{{' in x else x)
...         scope['env'].filters['q'] = lambda value: re.sub (r'"', r'\\"', value)
...         return scope['env'].from_string (tpl).render (**args)
... 
>>> render("this {{ outer_var }} wokring!", {"outer_var":"{{ inner_var }}", "inner_var":"{{ final_step }}", "final_step":"is"})
u'this is wokring!'
```

EDIT:

Ok, refactored my render function a bit, functionally the same, but a bit tidier:

```
def render (tpl, args):
    @jinja2.environmentfunction
    def finalize (env, value):
        if isinstance(value, (str, unicode)) and '{{' in value:
            return env.from_string (value).render (args)
        return value
    env = jinja2.Environment (finalize=finalize)
    env.filters['q'] = lambda value: re.sub (r'"', r'\\"', value)
    return env.from_string (tpl).render (args)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making X a macro.

```
import jinja2
tpl = '''
{% macro X(name) -%}
    {{name}}
{%- endmacro %}
Hello {{ X('world') }}!
'''
jinja2.Template(tpl).render()
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good way to do this nested rendering, however, I may try to suggest an alternatives:

Since the user create the posts, I imagine "{{some_other_variable}}" is actually substring of the whole post, which is also a string.

I would do:

```
X.replace("{{some_other_variable}}", some_other_variable))
```

then return {{X}} as per normal. Would that satisfy what you want to do?

Comment: Jinja2 replace would be better than this.
`{{ X|replace("{{Hello}}", "Goodbye") }}`

I need more native solution than that.

Comment: I'm certainly not the most experienced guy out there. I would be glad to know if there is any particular reason making jinja2 replace better. In addition, what do you mean by 'native'? As in closest to Jinja2 as possible?

Comment: oh yes, I definitely mean closest to Jinja2 as possible. I just waiting for more generic solution by which I could add whole jinja2 capabilities (not just variable replacement) in these scenarios. Otherwise, I would offer bounty to variable replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work with template files and environment globals.

```
def render(template, values):
     prev = template.render(**values)
     while True:
         curr = Template(prev).render(siteinfo=config, menus=menus, blended_header=header, authors=authors, buildinfo=buildinfo, **values)
         if curr != prev:
             prev = curr
         else:
             return curr
```

In this version, you have to pass the environment globals to the render function inside of this function, and the function it's self has to be in your build function.

The way to send content to it is: `render(template, dict(content=post, tags=tags))`

where `template = env.get_template('index.html')`