# Jinja nested template inside variable in template

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to do custom notification system. Right now i have table in database, that have html code, what i put on my page.
But if I insert jinja expressions into this code, they are displayed as plain text.

Example:

```py
def render():
    hidden_variable = "world"
    example = "Hello {{hidden_variable}}!"

    return {'example': example, 'hidden_variable': hidden_variable}
```

template.html

```html
<div>
{{example}}
</div>
```

What i get:

```
Hello {{hidden_variable}}!
```

What i want:

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jinja nested rendering on variable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862731/jinja-nested-rendering-on-variable-content)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use nested jinja templates:

```py
nested_template = 'my_custom_template'
hidden_variable = 'hello world'
```

`base_template.html.j2`

```
{% include 'nested/' + nested_template + '.html.j2' %}
```

`nested/my_custom_template.html.j2`

```
{{ hidden_variable }}
```

Answer (score 3):

That **example** is being stored as string because you are using jinja syntax inside a python function.

Jinja is a web template engine for the Python.

Instead:

```
example = f"Hello {hidden_variable}!"
```